# YouTube video plays without sound when downloaded?

Tags: vlc-media-player, youtube

I have downloaded a few videos from YouTube using [IDM (Internet Download Manager)](https://www.internetdownloadmanager.com) (all MP4).
When I opened the video in VLC media player, a black screen appeared and started flickering. The video just does not start.

What all I things I did:

1. Updated my VLC.
2. Reinstalled my VLC.
3. Downloaded another media player ([Wondershare](https://www.wondershare.com); very very beautiful I must say). It played the video but audio was missing.
4. converted MP4 to FLV and then played in both players, still no sound.

Its very frustrating as I want to complete my tutorial series asap. FLV files works well, but MP4s fall flat.

What should I do?

Comment: These kind of things appear mostly on codec mismatches. Using K-lite codec pack and BS Player with allowing it to download/upgrade available codecs via its Codec Manager solves my problems.

Comment: @The_aLiEn:sorry but i dint understood it,i am not that of tech guy

Comment: V/A files are stored as encrypted files, more commonly say digitalised as their **original** state was analog. The players has to decrypt them in order to see what is inside and play them. The helper encryption-decryption files are **codes**. You can download K-Lite pack from [here](http://www.free-codecs.com/download_soft.php?d=7478&s=775&r=) and BS Player from [here](http://www.bsplayer.com/). First install K-Lite and then install BS Player, after installations, lunch BS and it'll say which codec should be downloaded and when you say it to download it'll download and install automatically.

Comment: is it not possible to correct this using vlc..or downloading k-lite is the only solution?

Comment: K-Lite is a compilation of codecs, as your VLC player can use. (correcting above comment: "...The helper encryption-decryption files are code'c's. You can...")

Comment: so i install this codec and then play video in my vlc without any bsplayer would work fine?what is codec by the way..

Comment: It sould work. I recommend BS player to you for it's codec manager as it could detect missing ones. Me using BS is another thing ;) You can continue using VLC as long as you want. I was going to explain what a codec is shortly but i accidently pressed enter, then i edited the above comment. Repeating, Video and Audio files are stored as encrypted files, more commonly say digitalised as their original state was analog. The players has to decrypt them in order to see what is inside and play them. The helper encryption-decryption files are the codecs.

Comment: so now i have klite,vlc,windows media player and wondershare...is it ok if i have 4 players on my system..

Comment: Players are just players.. It's like having Notepad, Wordpad and Word to read from *.txt files.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10304/discussion-between-vagabond-and-the-alien)

Comment: Quick chat outline: Vagabond has normal (mp3) sounds working in videos. Has 2 different players now BS and VLC, and has used K-Lite codec. AAC based codec sounds (in videos) are not playing through simple stereo headphones still. The video pictures is there, but no sounds.

Comment: headphones and speaker....not playing on both of them..

Comment: I just checked the AAC codecs options, and there are many options in its configuration that could lead to such a problem. It allows for and redirects what speakers it goes to, and can set for SPDIF (no sound at all to any speakers). If the options in the AAC filter are set wrongly, it could have the symptoms your getting.  In the media program I am using I can get to those options, in Audio Filters.  Different programs will access it different. Try to locate The AAC codec/filter options, and test.

Comment: @Psycogeek:yesterday,i downloaded the same video and guess what..this time the audio played,but the video dint..haha!!!i will test it ..surely

Comment: just update your idm, then it will sure contain the sound

Answer (score 1):

I think some of youtube videos are somehow get the video and audio file separated so when you download the video the file itself contain no audio. Try to go back to the site and download the audio file, and insert it to the video. it always have extension .m4a

Comment: extention would be webm